# Splitting cells in the middle in a latex table

Tags: tables

I was making a presentation on latex and I ran into a bit of trouble making the following table:

[image]

I'm sorry if the image isn't clear but I'll explain what I want to do here. First, I was looking to merge four rows together which is easily done with `\multirow{4}{*}{...}` but then I want to split the same column into two, with the other split half of the column being unmerged. I know an easy way out would be to introduce the columns explicitly at the very beginning and keep using `\multicol{2}{l}{...}` for all the other rows. But I want to avoid that because the size of the text in the other rows in the same column may end up exceeding what I account for in the table definition. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: That table has 4 columns. Would you please post an example of the problem with the text mentioned? The width of the columns could be set to any appropriate value.

Comment: Cells can not be split but only merged. So you should define table with four columns and merged cells where needed (for cells with 2 and 5).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `p` column type instead of `l` to have fixed width columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1in}|p{.5in}|p{.5in}|p{1in}|}
\hline
1 & \multicolumn{2}{p{1in}|}{some really long text that wraps lines} & 3\\\hline
4 & \multicolumn{2}{p{1in}|}{5} & 6\\\hline
7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\\cline{3-4}
&  & some really long text that wraps lines & 12\\\cline{3-4}
&  & 13 & 14\\\cline{3-4}
&  & 15 & 16\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I solved this by merging cells today just as it was mentioned. And I did use p{some number in terms of \textwidth} for my solution. Thanks all of you